# How can I make this generic and pass any enum to it?

Tags: c#, generics, enums

Okay, it's time I learned arguments, parameters, generics... Oh yay me!! I see how to use explicit typing but have no clue as to making this method generic and pass in the enum of choice. Any advice/"tutor code" would be great.

```
using System;

public class Program

{
    enum FarmAnimals { Cow = 1, Chicken, Goat, Horse }
    
    enum ForrestAnimals { Lion = 1, Tiger, Elephant, Panther, Monkey }

    enum SeaAnimals{ Whale = 1, Shark, Eel, Tuna, Swordfish, Dolphin, Sealion }

    public static void Main()
    
    {
        Test();
    }

    static void Test()
    {
        bool whatever = true;
        bool ok;
        int pick = 0;

        foreach (FarmAnimals animals in Enum.GetValues(typeof(FarmAnimals)))
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(animals);
            String name = Enum.GetName(typeof(FarmAnimals), animals);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", id, name);
        }

        while (whatever == true)
        {
            Console.Write("Pick a number ");
            String line = Console.ReadLine();
            ok = int.TryParse(line, out pick);

            if (ok)
            {
                int counter = Enum.GetValues(typeof(FarmAnimals)).Length;
                if (pick < 1 || pick > counter)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have an invalid number! You used {0}.", pick);               
                }
                else
                {
                    FarmAnimals animals = (FarmAnimals)pick;
                    Console.WriteLine("Great! You picked: {0}", animals);
                    
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please pick a number.");     
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Make _what_ method generic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your code have endless loop. There must be an exit condition.**

Bellow code remove endless loop and use generic method, You can pass any enum to it

```
public static void Test<T>() where T : Enum
{
    Type enumType = typeof(T);

    foreach (T enumValue in Enum.GetValues(enumType))
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", Convert.ToInt32(enumValue), Enum.GetName(enumType, enumValue));

    while (true)
    {
        Console.Write("Pick a number ");
        string line = Console.ReadLine();
        int pick;

        bool ok = int.TryParse(line, out pick);

        if (ok)
        {
            if (pick < 1 || pick > Enum.GetValues(enumType).Length)
                Console.WriteLine("You have an invalid number! You used {0}.", pick);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Great! You picked: {0}", Enum.GetName(enumType, pick));

            break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Please pick a number.");
    }
}
```

And then, you can use it like this

```
Test<SeaAnimals>();
Test<ForrestAnimals>();
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't expecting an outright answer. I was hoping for tutor code (where you add comments throughout the code) or something. I'll dissect it and study it that way. Thank you so much.